# How to get rid of vim status line flickering when switching tab?

Tags: vim, tmux, rxvt, urxvt

I want to replace xfce4-terminal to urxvt but there is flickering of lines with `bg` property set (tabline, statusline) when switching tabs in vim (or neovim). I have no issue using xfce4-terminal which I have chosen for that reason (I used xterm before). But urxvt works faster and I do really like low-latency apps. I have found that under tmux I have no flickering but when I disable its status line everything comes back. I do not use tmux and I have just installed it cause some guy mentioned it. I do not mind to use tmux or gnu screen (have no effect under it) if it is invisible (not with statusline or whatever else).

`man urxvt` says I am using 9.22 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am glad I have found this [issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/4210). In order to get rid of annoying flickering define `ctermbg` property for `Normal` syntax group in your color scheme, like this:

```
hi Normal ctermfg=12 ctermbg=8 cterm=NONE
```

Color #8 should match with your terminal background color. I use solarized theme, so I have

```
*background: #002b36
*color8: #002b36
```

in my `~/.Xresources`.